# Exception caught by widgets library -The following StateError was thrown building: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am new to flutter and i am building a social media App through tutorial which i am now customizing. Now I tried to add more detailed post form for user post and diplay those input back on the main page then i started getting the error below. When i could login my timeline page turned red with warning Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

this are my code:

```
import 'package:campushubb/components/drawer.dart';
import 'package:campushubb/components/wall_post.dart';
import 'package:campushubb/pages/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dot_navigation_bar/dot_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:campushubb/pages/event_form.dart';

// Define an enum for the selected tab
enum _SelectedTab { home, calender, post, search, profile }

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // User
  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  // Text controller
  final textController = TextEditingController();

  // User sign out
  void signOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  // post message
  void postMessage() {
    //only post if there is something in the textfield
    if (textController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      //store in the firebase
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Event Posts").add({
        'UserEmail': currentUser.email,
        'Message': textController.text,
        'TimeStamp': Timestamp.now(),
        'Likes': [],
        'EventName': textController.text,
        'date': textController.text,
        'location': textController.text,
        'description': textController.text,
      });
    }

    //clear the textfield
    setState(() {
      textController.clear();
    });
  }

  //navigate to profile page
  void goToProfilePage() {
    //pop menu drawer
    Navigator.pop(context);

    //go to profile page
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ProfilePage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Handle tab changes
  _SelectedTab _selectedTab = _SelectedTab.home;

  void _handleIndexChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedTab = _SelectedTab.values[index];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //navbar
      bottomNavigationBar: DotNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _SelectedTab.values.indexOf(_selectedTab),
        onTap: _handleIndexChanged,
        items: [
          DotNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            selectedColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          DotNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            selectedColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          DotNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up_rounded),
            selectedColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          DotNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            selectedColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          DotNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_2_outlined),
            selectedColor: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        /*
        title: const Center(
          child: Text("CampusHub"),
        ),
        actions: [],
        */
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(
        onProfileTap: goToProfilePage,
        onSignOut: signOut,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // CampusHub
          Expanded(
            child: _selectedTab == _SelectedTab.post
                ? EventFormPage() // Display EventFormPage when "post" tab is selected
                : StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("Event Posts")
                        .orderBy(
                          "TimeStamp",
                          descending: false,
                        )
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapShot) {
                      if (snapShot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapShot.data!.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            //get the message
                            final post = snapShot.data!.docs[index];
                            return WallPost(
                              message: post['Message'],
                              user: post['UserEmail'],
                              postId: post.id,
                              likes: List<String>.from(post['Likes'] ?? []),
                              eventName: post['EventName'],
                              eventDate: post['date'],
                              eventLocation: post['location'],
                              eventDescription: post['description'],
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } else if (snapShot.hasError) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Text('Error:${snapShot.error.toString}'),
                        );
                      }
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
          ),

          // Post event
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // Text field
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: textController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          ),
                          hintText: 'Post your event...',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // Post button
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: postMessage,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up_rounded),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i already tried everything that i can to fix this but it seems like nothing happened